# Intuition for why $\int_0^\infty\frac{1-(1+x^2)^{-a/2}}{x^2}\,dx$ should equal $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-|\cos x|^a}{x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $a>0$. One can calculate the following integral identities: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{a/2}}}{x^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2}+\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2})}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-|\cos x|^a}{x^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2}+\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2})}$$

Miraculously, these two integrals give the same result.

Does anyone have any high-level intuitive explanation for why this happens?

Comment: We could rewrite the expression as $\frac{\pi}{B\left(\frac x2,\frac12\right)}$. I don't know what else we can do.

Answer (score 7):

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-|\cos x|^a}{x^2} \, dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\frac{1-|\cos x|^a}{\sin^2x} \, dx$$
Using  [Lobachevsky integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula)
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-|\cos x|^a}{\sin^2x} \, dx\overset{IBP}{=}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cot x\left(-(\cos^2x)^{a/2}\right)'_xdx=a\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^axdx$$
$$=\frac a2B\left(\frac a2+\frac12;\frac12\right)=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2}+\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{a}{2})}\tag{1}$$
( [Beta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) )

Next,
$$I_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{a/2}}}{x^2} \, dx\overset{IBP}{=}a\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{\frac a2+1}}=\frac a2\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt t(1+t)^{\frac a2+1}}$$
$$\overset{x=\frac1{1+t}}{=}\frac a2\int_0^1(1-x)^{-\frac12}x^{\frac a2-\frac12}dx=\frac a2B\left(\frac a2+\frac12;\frac12\right)\tag{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,I_1=I_2$$

Comment: (+1) Or more directly (without refering to Beta and Gamma functions):
$$I_1=[...]=a\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^axdx$$
$$I_2=[...]=a\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{\frac a2+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,I_1=I_2.$$

Comment: Ah yes,  it's obvious

Comment: unfortunately I still do not understand intuitively why I_1 = I_2... it seems to me that a long calculation magically gives this identity

Comment: As @ Anne Bauval pointed out in the comment, $I_1=I_2$ even without addressing to Beta-function. Namely, making the substitution $x=\tan t$
$$I_2=a\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{\frac a2+1}}\overset{x=\tan t}{=}a\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{\cos^2t\,(1+\tan^2t)^{\frac a2+1}}=a\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^at\,dt=I_1$$
In fact you consider the same integral.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x=\tan \theta$ transforms the integral into
$$
I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-\cos ^2 \theta}{\sin ^2 \theta} d \theta
$$
Integration by parts on $\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =a \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^a \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{a}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{a+1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{a}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This amounts to @Svyatoslav's work for "$I_2$", but does not explain why it is equal to "$I_1$".

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me the careless mistake in the last line.  Fixed it.